# query on observable collection and add those result to a list box?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Actually i have an observable collection with details of professionals like name,role,industry,region,language etc., i want to group those details in list box by different categories like according to region and accrding to langugage etc., can any one help me in this..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to query your collection according to any property you want

```
var GroupedByRegion=from c in myobservableCollection
                    group c by c.Region into g
                    select new {Region = g.Key , Items=g};

var GroupedByLanguage=from c in myobservableCollection
                      group c by c.Language into g
                      select new {Language= g.Key , Items=g};
```